# Esbuild in Phoenix + jQuery

Tags: jquery, node-modules, phoenix-framework, esbuild

I currently use esbuild to load my static assets.
I use it with a package.json file to maintain my javascript plugins.
The jQuery plugin is available in my app.js, but not in my node_modules. The datepicker module errors: 'jQuery is not defined'

In webpack there was a ProvidePlugin module that fixed this. How should I do this with esbuild?

**app.js**

```
import jquery from "jquery";
window.jQuery = jquery;
window.$ = jquery;
$ = jquery;

import datepicker from "jquery-ui/ui/i18n/datepicker-nl-BE"

---->>>>> ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at datepicker-nl-BE.js:13 <<<<<--------
```

**dev.exs**

```
  watchers: [
    #esbuild: {Esbuild, :install_and_run, [:default, ~w(--sourcemap=inline --watch)]},
    node: ["esbuild.js", "--watch", cd: Path.expand("../assets", __DIR__)],
    node: ["sass-watch.js",
      cd: Path.expand("../assets", __DIR__),
      into: IO.stream(:stdio, :line),
      stderr_to_stdout: true
    ]
  ]
```

**esbuild.js**

```
const esbuild = require('esbuild')
const sassPlugin = require('esbuild-plugin-sass')

// Decide which mode to proceed with
let mode = 'build'
process.argv.slice(2).forEach((arg) => {
  if (arg === '--watch') {
    mode = 'watch'
  } else if (arg === '--deploy') {
    mode = 'deploy'
  }
})

const loader =
  {
    '.png': 'file',
    '.ttf': 'file'
  }

// Define esbuild options + extras for watch and deploy
let opts = {
  entryPoints: ['js/app.js'],
  bundle: true,
  logLevel: 'info',
  target: 'es2016',
  outdir: '../priv/static/assets',
  loader,
  plugins: [sassPlugin()]
}
if (mode === 'watch') {
  opts = {
    watch: true,
    sourcemap: 'inline',
    ...opts
  }
}
if (mode === 'deploy') {
  opts = {
    minify: true,
    ...opts
  }
}

// Start esbuild with previously defined options
// Stop the watcher when STDIN gets closed (no zombies please!)
esbuild.build(opts).then((result) => {
  if (mode === 'watch') {
    process.stdin.pipe(process.stdout)
    process.stdin.on('end', () => { result.stop() })
  }
}).catch((error) => {
  process.exit(1)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be solved with jquery-ui-dist